# passing a boost::function to a template; what class is boost::function

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

I need to pass a distance-function to a template. Therefore I use boost::function and boost::bind. But I do not understand what I have to pass for **class Distance**:

```
template<class DataType, class Point, class Distance>
class CoverTree
{
    Distance distance;
    ...
    public:
     CoverTree(const Distance& distance) : max_level(default_max_level), min_level(default_max_level), distance(distance) {}
    ...
}
```

the example by the author of the template looks like this:

```
float euclidian(const std::vector<float>& p1, const std::vector<float>& p2)
{
    ...
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CoverTree<float, std::vector<float>, float (*const)(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&)> tree(&euclidian);
    ...
}
```

Now this is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AllData myData;
    boost::function<float (const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&, const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&)> j_dist;
    j_dist = boost::bind(&AllData::jaccard_distance, myData, _1, _2);
    myData.AddData("C:\\...");
    cout<<j_dist(myData.DATAx.begin()+20, myData.DATAx.begin()+40)<<endl; //works fine
    CoverTree<float, vector<Frame>::const_iterator, ???> tree(&j_dist);
    ...
}
```

At first, can somone explain me what (*const) means or where I can read about this?
And second:
I think I wrote everything you need, to tell what to write for **???** but I don't get it.
I already tried:

```
boost::function<float (const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&, const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&)
```

and

```
float (*const) (const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&, const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&)
```

but this was nice try and error :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At first, can somone explain me what (*const) means or where I can read about this?

In the author's example the distance function is:

```
float euclidean(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&);
```

The argument passed to the `CoverTree` constructor is the address of that function i.e. `&euclidean`, which is a function pointer of type

```
float (*)(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&)
```

The template parameter for `CoverTree` is simply a `const`-qualified version of that type.  Due to the peculiar "inside out" declarator syntax for functions in C and C++, a const pointer to that function type is declared as:

```
float (* const)(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&)
```

This is analogous to a `const` pointer to `int`, which is declared as:

```
int* const
```

In your case, you got the type right, it's:

```
boost::function<float (const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&, const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&)
```

Let's use a typedef to refer to that:

```
typedef boost::function<float (const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&, const vector<Frame>::const_iterator&) distance_func;
```

but the problem is that you are not passing an argument of that type, you're passing a pointer to that type:

```
CoverTree<float, vector<Frame>::const_iterator, distance_func> tree(&j_dist);
                                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

You can see this won't work by doing:

```
distance_func f = &j_dist;  // ERROR! cannot convert distance_func* to distance_func
```

The answer should be to simply to pass an argument of the correct type:

```
CoverTree<float, vector<Frame>::const_iterator, distance_func> tree(j_dist);
                                                                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This compiles! How can I tag this as solved?

Comment: @user__42: Look for the checkmark icon near the top left of the answer.